# How can I compare two arrays in a WHERE?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I need to do a query to know if ARRAY2 contains all members of my ARRAY1.

Something like this:

```
    ->where("entity.array IN :array_in_parameters")
```

For example if `entity.array` contains the numbers 1 2 3 4 and `array_in_parameters` contains 1 2 3, it should select it.

Got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`, but it is going to be inefficient. You must find each element in `array_in_parameters` individually:

```
where find_in_set(1, entity.array) > 0 and
      find_in_set(2, entity.array) > 0 and
      find_in_set(3, entity.array) > 0
```

See more details [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php).